# Use Boostrap 4 without its components

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

Can I use [Boostrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/contents/#css-files) without its components? According to the below diagram, It doesn't support no?

*My Usecases:*

- I need to use Angular Material components instead of Bootstrap components.
- We can use Boostrap 4 without Jquery. That is fine.
- I need to reduce bundle size as much as small and it must support IE 11 and above too.
- I use Angular 8

Do you have a better workaround for this?

[image]

***i.e.*** According to the above chart, I can use `bootstrap-grid.min.css` for the grid system. But how can I use `Layout`, `Content` and `Utilities` CSS of Boostrap without `Components`?

Comment: @Pete According to the above chart, I can use `bootstrap-grid.min.css` for the grid system. But how can I use `Layout`, `Content` and `Utilities` CSS of Boostrap?

Comment: I guess you could use npm to install bootstrap then choose which scss files you want to compile instead of using the standard https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/scss/bootstrap.scss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You install Bootstrap and then compile it with the options you want. Make sure you're using Sass for styles with your Angular project.

```
npm install bootstrap
```

**styles.scss**:

```
// these must be imported, but don't increase bundle size.
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// root adds variables to the CSS scope
@import "~bootstrap/scss/root";

// reboot is optional, but most people use it
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";

// everything else is optional. Comment out what you don't need
@import "~bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/transitions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/button-group";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/input-group";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/custom-forms";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/card";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/pagination";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/badge";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/alert";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/progress";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/list-group";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/close";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/modal";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/tooltip";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/popover";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/carousel";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";
```

The prefix `~` tells `node_sass` to find the imports in the `node_modules`. This depends upon which version of Angular you're using (Angular stopped using node_sass recently), but it should be compatible with all versions. I still use it with version 8.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get this? `then compile it with the options you want` I use Angular 8 and webpack behind the scenes since I use Angular CLI. So?

Comment: @Sampath it just means to compile your Angular with the CLI as you normally would. For example; `ng serve` and then the Bootstrap styles are compiled into the Webpack for you. Do not load the Bootstrap CSS files via the `index.html`! That will just create a duplicate of Bootstrap. The above will make the styles part of your app's internal CSS styles.

Comment: Can you tell me which SCSS will give `Layout`? i.e. `Grid` and etc:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: @Sampath `container`, `container-fluid` and the `col-*` grid classes are all in the `~bootstrap/scss/grid` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll see it.

Comment: You can easily add links to your styles in the index.html in Angular. You wont get duplicates if you simply remove the style reference from your angular.json settings file. Angular sticks those styles into internal embedded pages via Javascript which is quite nasty, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You install `Bootstrap` and then `compile` it with the options you want. Make sure you're using `Sass`

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like SASS, or the idea of compiling style sheets, just link to the full version of Bootstrap in your site or via an external content provider. You have everything you may or may not need without extra steps, compiling, or dependencies.

I then bolt in a custom style sheet I built that RESETS or reverts Bootstrap's reboot or other element sheets back to browser default UA style settings. Example....this would clear out all Bootstrap's custom fonts and text settings inherited by all the pages children. You can then add in your own without affecting their custom classes. Note this works in IE and non-IE browsers by using fallback properties then "all:revert" for newer browsers who can reset property values back to the default browser style sheet:

```
html body {
    display: block;
    margin: initial;
    zoom: 1;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: initial;
    padding: initial;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    color: initial;
    text-align: initial;
    background-color: initial;
    all: revert;
}
```

You get a clean style of your html but still can still add Bootstrap's custom classes as an option. Whats great about this fix is you still have access to Bootstrap's full package in every web application but can quickly reset their styles back to browser defaults by pasting in your external cleaner style sheet.

Simple is Better :)